# QooxDoo Application Types

Tags: qooxdoo

I am new to qooxdoo framework I have few questions,

1. In all the sample QX.Website apps provided there was no QXTheme defined in config.json, is it like themes are used in a different way instead of config.json or how?
2. Is qooxdoo is like replacement for jquery or will be used together with jquery. Since jquery has lot of plugins available. I am not finding qooxdoo as easy as jquery

3.QX.Desktop is desktop feel like website or it is a desktop application itself, same for qx.mobile too?

I am working on a POC it will be of great help.

Comment: What kind of PoC?

Answer (score 1):

- QX Website
  Is cross-browser library that can help you build lightweight websites.
  It main features are DOM selector, BOM and HTML abstraction layers, cross-browser keyboard and pointer events. As well some network abstractions for REST service and web storage. Οther functionality is provided through modules. There is no theming option because theming is done by regular css.
  You can see an overview of the modules [here](http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/pages/website/modules.html#).
- QX mobile
  Is the attempt to enable developers use the same principals as in qx.desktop to create web apps that have that feels likes a native app or you can simply use cordova or something else to ship your application inside any store.
- QX Desktop
  Is the way to go if you are building a single page application.
  It has the feeling of a desktop application but this is only theming and it runs in the browser it doesn't run on desktop.

TIPS

- If you want to build a mobile app don't use qx mobile as I don't think is maintained appropriate anymore.
- If you would like to have a more modern theme checkout the clean theme from [sqville](https://github.com/sqville/sqv).
- If your project have a lot of forms and think to use [qookery](http://www.qookery.org/content/waffle/qookerydemo/index.html#demo.helloWorld) as it will be easier. (Shameless plug I'm one of the contributors of qookery).